# How to create wrapper child component for react navigator

Tags: typescript, react-native

Tab.Navigator component can only have Tab.Screen component as a direct child component.

In Typescript, is there any way to cast Tab.Screen Type to TabButton function??

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
        ...>
        <Tab.Screen name={'name1'} component={component1} />
        <Tab.Screen name={'Add Photos'} component={FeedScreen}
                    options={{
                      tabBarButton: ...
        />
        <TabButton title={'Setting'} component={SettingScreen} imageSrc={'./icons/accountDark.png'}/>

}
```

Here is what I am trying to do

```
type TabButtonProps = {
  title: string,
  component: any,
  imageSrc: string,
}
const TabButton = ({title, component, imageSrc}: TabButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Screen name={title} component={component} options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', top: 10}}>
          <Image source={imageSrc as ImageSourcePropType}
                 resizeMode='contain'
                 style={{width: 25, height: 25, tintColor: focused ? '#999999' : '#dddddd'}}
          />
        </View>
      )}}/>
  )
}
```

what i've got:

```
Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen' components as its direct children (found 'TabButton'). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about TypeScript, so casting will not solve this.
You could use a component generate instead of a wrapped component:

```js
const createTabButton = ({title, component, imageSrc}: TabButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Screen name={title} component={component} options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', top: 10}}>
          <Image source={imageSrc as ImageSourcePropType}
                 resizeMode='contain'
                 style={{width: 25, height: 25, tintColor: focused ? '#999999' : '#dddddd'}}
          />
        </View>
      )}}/>
  )
}

...

const App = () => {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
        ...>
        <Tab.Screen name={'name1'} component={component1} />
        <Tab.Screen name={'Add Photos'} component={FeedScreen}
                    options={{
                      tabBarButton: ...
        />
        {createTabButton({title: 'Setting', component: SettingScreen,  imageSrc:'./icons/accountDark.png'})}
    <NavigationContainer/>
}
```

You might also be able to "trick" the library by setting the display name:

```js
TabButton.displayName = 'Tab.Screen'
```